# Calling tab of a Activity from other Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a MainActivity and I am using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout for the tabview with Viewpager.

Now If i am in some other activity and from this activity if I want to go to the 3rd tab of the MainActivity, how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following.

at the `MainActivity` class at the `onCreate` method after initializing the tabLayout write below code

```
int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("SelectedIndex",0);
tabLayoutObject.getTabAt(index).select();
```

And from place from where you want to redirect to `MainActivity` write following

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SelectedIndex",2) //what ever the index is
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

you can return to the first acticity with a value of some sort which will indicate you need to go to the third tab
in the on create you will check if the value is in the intent getextra 
if it is-go to the third 
else-continue regulary

Answer (score 0):

You can putExtra before create activity and get it in second activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use startActivityForResult() while going to SecondActivity.

When you are using startActivityForResult you can get notify in you firstActivity using setResult();

**In FirstActivity :**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == 0){
                if(data!=null && data.getExtras()!=null){
                    final int position = data.getIntExtra("key_position",-1);
                    if(position !=-1){
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**In SecondActivity :**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("key_position",3);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

It will help you.